# Copy duplicate file and change name

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i'm looking to make a backup of this file every two times, for a maximum of 30 backups at once. Once there is 30 backups, the function deletes all the backups and starts all over again (again, creating 30 backups, once every two seconds).

Because i'm creating 30 copies of the same file, I need to change the name so python dosen't overwrite the file (main0.db, main1.db, main2.db, main3.db...etc). In order to do this, i've created a variable that gets appended to the filename (i) and increased by 1 each time the function runs.

The problem is that because I have to(?) decalre the variable inside the function, every time it runs the variable gets reset, and so the only file that is created is main0.db.

Any ideas?

Hey, so i'm looking to make a backup of this file every two times, for a maximum of 30 backups at once. Once there is 30 backups, the function deletes all the backups and starts all over again (again, creating 30 backups, once every two seconds).

Because i'm creating 30 copies of the same file, I need to change the name so python dosen't overwrite the file (main0.db, main1.db, main2.db, main3.db...etc). In order to do this, i've created a variable that gets appended to the filename (i) and increased by 1 each time the function runs.

The problem is that because I have to(?) decalre the variable inside the function, every time it runs the variable gets reset, and so the only file that is created is main0.db.

Any ideas?

```
import os

import glob

import threading

import shutil

def check():

 i = 0

 threading.Timer(2, check).start()

 listPath = 'C:\Users\Billy\Desktop\New folder'
 num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(listPath)
             if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(listPath, f))])
 #counts all the files in the directory  

 if num_files < 30:
        copyPath = 'C:\Users\Billy\Desktop\New folder\main%d.db' % i 
        i + 1   
        shutil.copy2('C:\main.db', copyPath)
 else:
        files = glob.glob('C:\Users\Billy\Desktop\New folder\*')
        for f in files:
            os.remove(f)
        i = 0
 #if theres less than 30 files, creates a copy of the file, iterates filename by 1 
 #else deletes all files in that folder, resets file name iterator to 0.

 return

check()
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use threading for this rather than a simple for loop? If you really want/need the threading, then I'd pass the new file name to be created to the thread, and have the logic for incrementing/deleting files in the main thread.

Comment: @TomDalton I want the function to run continuously, without stopping, every two seconds. Wouldn't a for loop require me to set a limit?

Comment: You could have a `for i in xrange(30):` for the file-numbering and a `while True:` loop around that for the delete/reset. Threading might be useful if the file copy takes a long time, but my guess is that it doesn't?

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could fix the indentation and remove the ref to `num_files` as it looks like it's unused.

Comment: Finally, if you gave us the background on why you need to do exactly this, we might be able to suggest alternative ways to achieve what you're trying to do

Comment: @TomDalton Awesome, I didn't know about xrange. I'll try and use that now. Thanks. Im trying to create a rolling backup of one of my files, which I can stop (or that stops automatically) when the file changes. Becuase the file is locked i can't just constantly/automatically check for different hashes and only make a backup then.

 This is probably a really roundabout way but it should work. I tried to fix the indentation as best I can, i'm also not sure what you mean by the num_files ref, all the mentions of that in my code are used (that i can see). Cheers

Comment: Where is `num_files` used in the code you've pasted above? Edit - nevermind, it's late and I'm blind :)

Comment: Would you prefer to keep the last 30 files always, e.g. if there are 30 then delete the oldest before you make a new one?

Comment: @TomDalton No it would be better for me if I kept the last 30 files.

Comment: I would imply the "next" value of `i` from the last created. In other words, I would change the backup file names to main.db.0, main.db.1,... and when you scan the directory you would list main.db.*, and then find out what the largest number in main.db.(num) is, and use that to create the (num+1) copy.